# Mix serial ports and sockets cross-platform?

Tags: python, sockets, serial-port, cross-platform

I have a simple serial control interface (and protocol) that I'm expanding to also work over a socket (for remote access and users without serial ports).  The current code is cross-platform, and I'd like to keep it that way, as well as add network support with minimal changes to working code.

The problem is monitoring each control port (serial and/or connected socket).  I can't use `select()` because on Windows it won't accept serial ports.  So I need to iterate over each port to check for commands.  So I set both the serial ports and the sockets to be non-blocking (or extremely short timeout, as appropriate).

But sockets use recv()/send(), and serial ports use read()/write().  So when accept() returns a connection, I'm crudely adding read() and write() methods:

```
try:  # Non-blocking parent socket throws exception when no client waiting.
    conn, __ = parent_sock.accept()
    conn.write = conn.send
    conn.read = conn.recv
except:
    pass  # Nobody trying to connect()
```

And my processing loop looks like this:

```
while True:
    for iface in (ser_port, conn):
        try:
            cmd = iface.read(256)
            reply = doCmd(cmd)
            iface.write(reply)
        except:
           pass  # Not really... Handle socket exceptions.
```

This works! (At least for initial testing.)  But is this the best way to go?  I suspect there is a shiny package out there that handles precisely this situation, but so far Google gives me no love.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest distinguishing between connection types when you get them; then either recording this information (i.e. conn.method = 'serial') or creating or return the appropriate connection object (e.g. SerialConnection or SocketConnection: a class that implements generic read() or write() methods and abstracts the underlying differences between methods).